# AWS athena dpu usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How can we caluculate the dpu usage of aws athena in real time.we had gone through all the cloud-metrics but there is no metric to show the dpu usage.

to create an alaram that have to shown in real time the current dpu usage of athena.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to check dpus used by a query is through CloudWatch metrics. However, it is not useful for realtime monitoring as the dpu usage number is available only when the query has finished

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/query-metrics-viewing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Athena's provisioned capacity offering, you'd be able to view `DPUConsumed` metric for your workgroup under `AWS/Athena` namespace. This metric is real-time unlike the query metrics which are emitted end of the query.
Here's the AWS documentation for this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/query-metrics-viewing.html#athena-cloudwatch-metrics-table